# How to generate core dump on AddressSanitizer error

Tags: gcc, coredump, address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I compiled my code like this to enable Asan:

```
g++ -O0 -g -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer
```

but it never generates a core dump so that I can later examine the details of the error. How can I generate it?

Answer (score 32):

You need to set environment variable to request coredumps

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1
```

This should really be default but due to historic reasons ASan just exits with non-zero error code instead.

On 64-bit systems you might need to add

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS=abort_on_error=1:disable_coredump=0:unmap_shadow_on_exit=1
```

(coredumps are disabled by default there, in fear that they will be too large).

For complete list of flags you can see [Asan wiki](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags).

Comment: This is the only place on the net that I could find the correct answer for my 64-bit system. Thank you!

Comment: @the_endian Thank you. It's indeed sad to see that it's so hard to use Asan. Some complexity is justified (Asan has to do a lot of clever tricks) but IMO a larger chunk of it is due to inadequate/missing documentation.

Comment: `ERROR: expected '='`